# Bind POCO to UserControl

Tags: .net, data-binding, poco

Hi I am in the process of writing my first .net gui. I am wondering if there is some specific way I need to apply to my poco objects for them to be bindable to a usercontrol. I have a few objects but I seem to be unable to bind them to my usercontrol.

I read somewhere that they need to implement IBindable but I can't shake the feeling that someone already has eliminated all that duplicate code I would have to input into all my classes. Is there a way to easily bind these or would I have to use datasets or the like to be easily get this binding working. I have an extreme distaste for datasets to please present some other decent options ;-)

I am trying to bind to usercontrols from the devexpress toolkit.

Comment: What toolkit are you using? WinForms, WPF, GTK, ... ?

Comment: I am using winforms and devexpress.

Answer (score 1):

Which architecture?

For 1-way binding, you don't need anything other than public properties - and maybe some `TypeConverter` implementations for any bespoke data types (`struct`s etc)

For full 2-way binding, you'll need an eventing implementation - any of:

- a "public event EventHandler FooChanged" for every property "Foo"
- an `INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
- a bespoke component-model (don't go there - overkill)

For an example of a `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation (note you might want to move some of the code for re-use) :

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string bar;
    public string Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set { UpdateField(ref bar, value, "Bar"); }
    }
    // other properties...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T value,
        string propertyName)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

To bind *sets* of data (grids etc), the easiest thing is to use generics; basically, the *minumum* is `IList` - but you get extra metadata from a `public T this[int index]` indexer - which `List<T>`, `Collection<T>` etc all have. More - `BindingList<T>` implements `IBindingList` allowing collection-based notification events (but only to `INotifyPropertyChanged` - not to the `FooChanged` pattern).

Comment: I have properties that are of my custom objects as well which do not show up .. Person has property of Address which are both my poco objects. How do I bind Address ?

Comment: At the simplest? By overriding ToString() - but how are you showing it? Which control(s)?

Comment: For textbox, you should be able to use "Address.Line1" etc; for gridview you'll probably need a flattening (facade) object. If you want to edit the *entire* address in the textbox, you'll need a TypeConverter

Answer (score 0):

With WPF you'll need [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) or [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx). Also look into [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) for collections.

Answer (score 0):

The [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132683.aspx) can be used for binding to lists of generic objects.